# Why can't self be replaced in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

EDIT: For those criticizing my intentions with replacing `self`, you are free to click the back button, continue developing with your own opinions, and leave me to develop with mine :)

I was wondering if there is a way to completely remove the object that `self` references and replace it with a new instance.

Example:

```
def refresh_from_server!
  self = newly_fetched_object_from_server
end
```

I don't want to `return` the new object.

It seems like I would have to build my own copying interface and call `self.copy_from(other_object)` but maybe someone has a cool ruby bit to share that works better!

--EDIT

Since some people seem unclear on the question, I want `instance.my_method!` to completely replace `instance` with a new instance of that class

For example lets imagine we have a class

```
class Counter

  attr_accessor :count
  def initialize
    count = 0
  end

  def reset!
    # This is what I want to achieve.
    # Obviously in this case it would be trivial to write `self.count = 0`
    # Or return a new value
    # But I have a much more complex object in real life 
    # which copying would not be trivial
    # All I'm looking for is a bit of stylistic sugar to make my code look cooler
    # If it doesn't exist, I would love to know why
    self = Counter.new 
  end

  def up
    count += 1
  end

end
```

Comment: As with most (all?) OO languages, you cannot change `self` directly. The only things that change `self` are method calls and module (including class) definitions (source: [Dave Thomas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2sgQ38UDVY)).

Comment: Can you a bit more clarify what is the goal ? Changing receiver instead of implicit self is trivial, changing method's call binding is also trivial. Replacing implicit method's return value is also trivial.

Comment: There is no count++ in Ruby =)

Comment: I dare you to find a single OO language that allows replacing `self`.

Comment: @arthur.karganyan haha nice catch!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev **why**

Comment: @BrianWheeler: in doing so, you're likely to understand why no one does this.

Comment: Both String and Array provide a `replace` method, which replaces the content of `self` with the content  of another String/Array. That is about as far as it gets.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Smalltalk has `become:` which lets an object become another object, i.e. all references to that object are replaced with references of the other object (which may be of a different class). I'm not entirely sure, though, whether "all references" includes `self` or not. In some sense, it *must* include `self`, because after the object which is the receiver of `become:` *is* `self` at that particular point in time and gets replaced, but you could argue that the insides of `become:` are "magical" and thus the point in time where `self` changes in not observable.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't replace `self`. You can only change some/all of its state, but the object reference will remain the same.

Why would you want to do this, anyway? If you just want to piggyback on your initialization logic (as it seems to me to be the case), some refactoring will help: just call a shared method from both places.

```
class Counter

  attr_accessor :count

  def initialize
    init_state
  end

  def reset!
    init_state
  end

  def up
    self.count += 1
  end

  private

  def init_state
    self.count = 0
  end

end
```

Comment: He can't replace `self` but if replacement of a fresh instance is required, he can do that in a "class factory", ie. there is instance assignments register which can `Counter#reset!` invoke to reassign with a new instance.

Comment: Well the reason I want to do this is because I have an object that I am replacing from a server response. I could always create logic to copy it over but I already have that logic. Short of a major refactor there really isn't any other way

Comment: @BrianWheeler Server response is some JSON-like data, I assume? So you have logic that transforms this into objects? Why not just reuse it for copying?

Comment: @JoanBlackmoore: not sure I understand completely what you meant there.

Comment: It's more of a theoretical question at this point. I have a practical answer, but I am looking for a more high level overview

Comment: @BrianWheeler: not sure what you mean by "more high level overview". This answer can't get any more high level than "you just can't do that".

Answer (score 2):

Though the question is old, it is still visited. I will attempt to elaborate more on the "*why*" in "*Why can't self be replaced in Ruby?*".

**usage of `self` in which context**

https://web.archive.org/web/20191217060940/https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-self-cheat-sheet/

There are various contexts in which `self` can be used. You question uses it in the context of an instance method, so I will focus on that.

E.g. this context:

```
class SomeClass
  def some_method
    puts "#{self.class} - #{self.object_id} - #{self.inspect}"
  end
end
a = SomeClass.new
a.some_method
# prints : SomeClass - 47013616336320 - #<SomeClass:0x000055846bcd7b80>
```

Note that there are other usages of `self`: e.g. where it reference the `Class` object in scope of a class definition. E.g.

```
class SomeClass
  puts "#{self.class} - #{self.object_id} - #{self.inspect}"
end
# prints : Class - 47102719314940 - SomeClass
```

**the intended effect of replacing `self`**

Below code a demonstration of what you expected / wished (as I understand it):

```
class Counter
  def some_method
    puts "#{self.class} - #{self.object_id} - #{self.inspect}"
  end
  def refresh!
    self = Counter.new # not possible
    # results in error : "Can't change the value of self"
  end
end
a = Counter.new
a.some_method
# prints : Counter - 47013616336320 - #<Counter:0x000055846bcd7b80>
a.refresh!
# now you wish a to point to a different object
```

But what about other references? E.g. assuming you wanted:

```
a = Counter.new
b = a
a.some_method
b.some_method
# both print same : Counter - 47013616336320 - #<Counter:0x000055846bcd7b80>
a.refresh!
# now you wish both a and b to point to the same (new) object
```

If stated as such it gives a hint on the why not.

**why we can't replace `self`**

The short answer is that it is simply not something that the language / interpreter offers. As to the reasoning: in a way @matthewd answers that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51844851/2799887):

> All ruby variable references are essentially pointers (but not
>   pointers-to-pointers), in C parlance.
>
> You can mutate an object (assuming it's not immutable), and all
>   variables that reference it will thus be pointing at the same (now
>   mutated) object. But the only way to change which object a variable is
>   referring to is with direct assignment to that variable -- and each
>   variable is a separate reference; you can't alias a single reference
>   with two names.

In short: there may be other references to that object in variables that are not in the scope of the instance method. These cannot be manipulated by that instance method.

**a way to achieve the intended effect**

If you want this effect and only want to touch the code of `Counter` you might move all methods and state to an inner class `Counter::Inner` and make `Counter` behave like a decoupled reference. The only 'state' of `Counter` would be the reference to the `Counter::Inner` object and `Counter` can delegate all calls it receives to that reference in a [`method_missing`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) method. In case of your `refresh!` you can replace the reference in `Counter` same as you now intent to replace `self`. All outside code will now use indirectly the new `Counter:Inner` instance.

```
class Counter
  class Inner
    def some_method
      puts "#{self.class} - #{self.object_id} - #{self.inspect}"
    end
  end
  def initialize(*args)
    @reference = Inner.new(*args)
  end
  def method_missing(method_id, *args)
    @reference.send(method_id, *args)
  end
  def refresh!
    @reference = Inner.new
  end
end
a = Counter.new
b = a
a.some_method
b.some_method
# both print same : Counter::Inner - 46991238242100 - #<Counter::Inner:0x0000557a00203e68>
a.refresh!
a.some_method
b.some_method
# both print same : Counter::Inner - 46991238240000 - #<Counter::Inner:0x0000557a00202e00>
```

Just one more answer for the archives :-) I hope this gives useful insights to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted by others, `self` can't be replaced from enclosed instance. If replacement of instance with a new instance is required, it need to be done from outside, like in a class factory which registers its class instances.

Bellow is a simplest example using a delegator, demonstrating what I mean. SimpleDelegator represents a simple wrapper around Counter instance:

```
  require 'delegate'

  class Counter
    attr_accessor :count

    def initialize
      @count = 0
    end
  end

  class CounterDecorator < SimpleDelegator
    def reset!
      __setobj__(__getobj__.class.new)
    end
  end

  c = CounterDecorator.new(Counter.new)
  p c.__getobj__.object_id
  c.count = 123
  p c.count
  c.reset!
  p c.__getobj__.object_id
  p c.count

  # produces following output
  20131160
  123
  20130900
  0
```

Comment: Just add there is also a dirty way of direct replacement from inside of instance code through global variable reference like `def Counter.replace!; $counter_inst = self.class.new; end` but strongly discouraged practice.