# Pointer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pointers, linked-list, reference

I just solved some tasks about linked lists using Ruby. It was very interesting, but it requires a couple of new lines. Because if I pass `head` in some function, and change the head of the list, I have to return new `head` from method and reassign it to the variable.

Because if I have `a` variable and I pass it to method, reassign `a` inside, outside `a` dose not changes:

```
 it "dose not changes if reassign variable in method" do
        a = [1,2]
        def reasign array
            array = [1]
            array
        end
        assert_equal [1], reasign(a)
        assert_equal [1,2], a
    end
```

Of course I able to warp `head` of list in `Hash` or `Array` and save this `Hash` thus when I change something in object. The variable outside  still pointing on object. And this works. But again requires couple of lines.

```
it "method changes the data into a object" do
    a = [1,2]
    def change_object object
        object.push 3
        object
    end
    assert_equal [1,2,3], change_object(a)
    assert_equal [1,2,3], a
end
```

Is there way in Ruby to use C-like pointers or PHP-like references?

Comment: "Is there way in Ruby to use C-like pointers or PHP-like references?" - no.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev there _is_ indeed a way: write an extension and access the memory in a way you like.

Comment: @mudasobwa: that would be in C, not in ruby :)

Comment: `require "fiddle"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ruby variable references are essentially pointers (but not pointers-to-pointers), in C parlance.

You can mutate an object (assuming it's not immutable), and all variables that reference it will thus be pointing at the same (now mutated) object. But the only way to change *which* object a variable is referring to is with direct assignment to that variable -- and each variable is a separate reference; you can't alias a single reference with two names.

Comment: So, it's a "no"? :)

Comment: No, it isn't. This isn't at all like c pointers. The only pointy thing about ruby references is that they point to an object. You can't do address math or mutate a piece of memory directly. Which is the entire premise of the question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what `"foo"[1...2] = "bar"` is if not a mutation of a memory directly? Also, I would say, ruby references are like [tag:c] references. not like [tag:c] pointers.

Comment: I'll agree the question's premise is mixed; an `a`-manipulating version of the first example couldn't be achieved with C pointers either (NB again, excluding pointer-pointers). The final paragraph _asks_ about pointers, but by context seems to be more interested in pointer-pointers.

Comment: @mudasobwa: nope, not like c references either. Java references is the closest thing.

Comment: @matthewd: I am not familiar with term "pointer-pointer". What did you mean by that?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev damn, I again messed [tag:c] and [tag:cpp] :( I meant pass by reference as in `void func(int& ref) {ref++;}` which is obviously [tag:cpp].

Comment: @Sergio a pointer to a pointer. A ruby variable reference is a bit like `RVALUE*` (heh) -- yes, without the ability to do maths on it -- but there's no way to get an `RVALUE**`.

Comment: @matthewd "n a-manipulating version of the first example couldn't be achieved with C pointers either" - I haven't touched C in like 15 years, but I'm pretty sure it _is_ possible. In fact, that's how C people implement lists (I imagine). Check this: https://eval.in/1047568

Comment: Yeah, that's a pointer to an intrinsic.. I was thinking in the context of a malloc-managed struct.. which was maybe too over-specific.

Comment: Being clever it is quite possible to use `__id__` to get the real address in memory to the actual underlying struct. Obviously very hack-ish and requires knowing the exact layout each data type, altering memory in a language that seems to purposefully make it difficult, etc, but it is possible. This does not mean it should ever be done. If this is required, make a C extension to do it right.